# How to Search and Find in Txt file. Then Using The Found Variable

Tags: php, search, text, find

OK, this is Another Project Im Working ON.

Its a Chat Client. and Using it For Staff

I want the server to have a staff.txt on it.

and I want the php file to do this.

Execute the php.

if The Submitted Username is Found in the staff.txt then

The Username changes to [Staff]"Username Here"

I got the search and find down.

I Cant seem to keep the username that was submitted, and just adding staff to it.

Im Adding my Source Now.

```
<?php
// Parameters (Leave this Alone)
 $Message = $_GET["message"];
 $Username = htmlspecialchars($_GET["username"]);
 $time = ($_GET["time"]);
 // User Banning
 $data = file_get_contents('Banned.txt');
 if(strpos($data, $Username) !== FALSE)
{
   die();
 }
 else
{

 // File Writing (Leave this Alone) 
 $File = "Chat.txt"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, "a"); 
 fwrite($Handle, $Username);
 fwrite($Handle, ": ");
 fwrite($Handle, $Message);
  fwrite($Handle, " -:-:- ");
  fwrite($Handle, $time);
  fwrite($Handle, "\r\n");
  print "Message Sent"; 
  fclose($Handle); 
 }
?>
```

I have user banning working, and i Want the Staff To Work in the same way.

Any Help would be appreciated

Trying it a different way

```
If ($Username=="!divider!StaffMember1")  $Username="!divider![Staff] StaffMember1"; 
If ($Username=="!divider!StaffMember2")  $Username="!divider![Staff] StaffMember2";
```

that seems to work fine in the php file thats running the php with everything else.

Is there  a way to have that list in a seperate file? .txt file or .php doesnt matter.

Comment: Looks like this is going to be slow. Why don't you use a database?

Comment: Well I have a Moderating Client, and Believe it or Not, Its not really a Chat System. What its being used for is like a Blog post kind of thing. So its not needed for it to be in a database.

Comment: You don't need a else if you die in the if. it's an implicit else.

Comment: maybe not really on topic, but Ron, you have a remarkable use of capital letters.

Comment: Do you mean to do `"[Staff]" . $Username;`? PHP [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry I suspect it's a German.

Comment: Not sure what you mean schleen, I dont want it using the staff tag for everyone, just the usernames that submit a message, and are found in the staff.txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it like the banlist:

```
<?php
 // Parameters (Leave this Alone)
 $Message = $_GET["message"];
 $Username = htmlspecialchars($_GET["username"]);
 $time = ($_GET["time"]);

// check staff
 $data = file_get_contents('staff.txt');
 if(strpos($data, $Username) !== FALSE)
     $Username = '[STAFF]' . $Username;

// User Banning
 $data = file_get_contents('Banned.txt');
 if(strpos($data, $Username) !== FALSE)
{
   die();
 }
 else
{

 // File Writing (Leave this Alone) 
 $File = "Chat.txt"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, "a"); 
 fwrite($Handle, $Username);
 fwrite($Handle, ": ");
 fwrite($Handle, $Message);
  fwrite($Handle, " -:-:- ");
  fwrite($Handle, $time);
  fwrite($Handle, "\r\n");
  print "Message Sent"; 
  fclose($Handle); 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Check My Edits, This way might be easier.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it really I think. Maybe try: `$Username = '!divider![STAFF]' . $Username;`

Comment: Then it Would Give Me !divider![STAFF]!divider!Username: Message

Comment: Then look at the code which inserts the !divider! and don't expect more comments from me. I'm out now.